# How to fix 'SettingWithCopyWarning' in pandas, even though I am using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error message while running my python script:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

This is the line that is generating the error:

```py
df.loc[:, 'user.byte_size'] = df['user.byte_size'].astype(int)
```

I am already using `.loc`. So why is this generating an error?

NOTE: I've run this program on two different systems, and the warning only generates on one of them. I've checked the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) versions, and they are equal. So could something be wrong with my system? Thank you!

So far, the only solution I have found is just ignoring the error:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Of course, this works, but I would rather have no warning at all. I couldn't really find anything of help in [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

Comment: "*I am already using '.loc'. So why is this generating an error?*" Most likely something you did **before**. Can you provide the full code?

Comment: The warning is because your `df` is a copy of a bigger dataframe somewhere. Go back to where you create your `df`, e.g. `df = bigDF.loc[something==True]` and do `df = bigDF.loc[something==True].copy()`. Or, in your assignment `bigDF.loc[df.index, 'user.byte_size'] = df['use.byte_size'].astype(int)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.